# Swift Game Scene change background with time or score?

Tags: swift, background, scene

I have a background image in my application which moves from top to bottom and repeats.
I want a different images to appear on to the screen after x amount of time.

Would this do?

When would be best to remove the initial bg to avoid too many layers?

```
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    let bgTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bg1.png")
    let moveBGanimation = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -bgTexture.size().height), duration: 4)
    let shiftBGAnimation = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: bgTexture.size().height), duration: 0)
    let moveBGForever = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([moveBGanimation, shiftBGAnimation]))

    var i: CGFloat = 0

    while i < 3 {

        bg = SKSpriteNode(texture: bgTexture)
        bg.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: bgTexture.size().height * i)
        bg.size.width = self.frame.width
        bg.zPosition = -2

        bg.run(moveBGForever)
        self.addChild(bg)

        i += 1


    }

    bg2Timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(self.moveBG2), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

}

func moveBG2() {

    let bg2Texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bg2.png")
    let moveBG2animation = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -bg2Texture.size().height * 2), duration: 8)
    let shiftBG2Animation = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: bg2Texture.size().height), duration: 0)
    let moveBG2Forever = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([moveBG2animation, shiftBG2Animation]))

    var j: CGFloat = 0

    while j < 3 {

        bg2 = SKSpriteNode(texture: bg2Texture)
        bg2.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: bg2Texture.size().height + bg2Texture.size().height * j)
        bg2.size.width = self.frame.width
        bg2.zPosition = -1.5


        bg2.run(moveBG2Forever)
        self.addChild(bg2)

        j += 1


    }



}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an idea that I came up with.

Refactor this piece of code:

```
let bgTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bg.png")
    let moveBGanimation = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -bgTexture.size().height), duration: 4)
    let shiftBGAnimation = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: bgTexture.size().height), duration: 0)
    let moveBGForever = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([moveBGanimation, shiftBGAnimation]))
```

to a method:

```
func runBgActions(bgTextureName: String) {
    let bgTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: bgTextureName)
    bg.texture = bgTexture
        let moveBGanimation = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -bgTexture.size().height), duration: 4)
        let shiftBGAnimation = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: bgTexture.size().height), duration: 0)
        let moveBGForever = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([moveBGanimation, shiftBGAnimation]))
    bg.removeAllActions()
    bg.run(moveBGForever)
}
```

Then, create another action and run it on a node that's not `bg`, maybe the scene itself.

```
let bg1Action = SKAction.run { runBgActions(bgTextureName: "bg1") }
let bg2Action = SKAction.run { runBgActions(bgTextureName: "bg2") }
let bg3Action = SKAction.run { runBgActions(bgTextureName: "bg3") }
let waitAction = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 10)
let sequence = SKAction.sequence([bg1Action, waitAction, bg2Action, waitAction, bg3Action, waitAction])
let repeatForeverAction = SKAction.repeatForever(sequence)
self.run(repeatForeverAction) // assuming self is the scene here
```

An alternative approach would be to use `SKAction.group` to execute the wait and shifting background actions at the same time, but I find that quite counter-intuitive to implement.

After seeing your code, this is what I have been able to come up with:

```
var bg = SKSpriteNode()

func runBgActions(bgTextureName: String) {
    let bgTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: bgTextureName)
    bg.texture = bgTexture
    bg.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.minX, y: self.frame.minY)
    let moveBGanimation = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -(bgTexture.size().height - self.frame.height)), duration: 4)
    let shiftBGAnimation = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: bgTexture.size().height - self.frame.height), duration: 0)
    let moveBGForever = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([moveBGanimation, shiftBGAnimation]))
    bg.removeAllActions()
    bg.run(moveBGForever)
}

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    var i: CGFloat = 0

    bg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bg1") // replace this with your first background's texture name
    bg.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.minX, y: self.frame.minY)
    bg.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    bg.size.width = self.frame.width
    bg.zPosition = -2
    self.addChild(bg)

    i += 1
    let bg1Action = SKAction.run { self.runBgActions(bgTextureName: "bg1") }
    let bg2Action = SKAction.run { self.runBgActions(bgTextureName: "bg2") }
    let bg3Action = SKAction.run { self.runBgActions(bgTextureName: "bg3") }
    let waitAction = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 10)
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([bg1Action, waitAction, bg2Action, waitAction, bg3Action, waitAction])
    let repeatForeverAction = SKAction.repeatForever(sequence)
    self.run(repeatForeverAction)
}
```

Comment: This looks great @Sweeper I'm just struggling implementing it correctly. I'm not too sure where's best to place each bit of code? And what order at the moment. I'll keep moving stuff around and I'm sure I'll get there. Thanks!

Comment: I think it's almost correct. Please see revised question. I need to declare bgTexture somewhere outside the function I think as I get error "Use of unresolved identifier "bgTexture" "

Comment: @AlexIngram I think it's because the parameter's name conflicted with the local variable. Edited now.

Comment: @AlexIngram Edited. Please have a look!

Comment: What is happening is the image is moving downwards and that is what is changing to bg2, bg3. Instead of the new image coming down from the top of the screen as a new image? Does this make sense?

Comment: I've posted an updated question which might make more sense.

Comment: @AlexIngram I think I finally fixed it for you. Check it out.

Comment: This doesn't quite run right, bg shifts a very little amount and not the full screen with a scrolling affect. I think it's to do with the moveBGanimation

Comment: See my revised code - This method is working perfectly however it's probably a bad way of doing it?

Comment: @AlexIngram Say your scene is 750x1334, make the top 750x1334px of the texture the same as the bottom 750x1334px. Also, the topic of this discussion seems to be shifting to "how to do a scrolling background" which is out of the scope of this question.